# css html safe file name picture background vs image tag

Tags: html, css

Hi recently I found this bug in my code.

this link "[http://www.zendez.com/beta/files/retreatphotos/larges/idretreat70/Mayacamas Ranch, Calistoga, California_ Paradise with a Purpose.jpg](http://www.zendez.com/beta/files/retreatphotos/larges/idretreat70/Mayacamas%20Ranch,%20Calistoga,%20California_%20Paradise%20with%20a%20Purpose.jpg)" is safe if I use it with

```
<img scr="http://www.zendez.com/beta/files/retreatphotos/larges/idretreat70/Mayacamas Ranch, Calistoga, California_ Paradise with a Purpose.jpg">
```

but is not valid well at least the image dont show if I use

```
<div style="background:url(http://www.zendez.com/beta/files/retreatphotos/larges/idretreat70/Mayacamas Ranch, Calistoga, California_ Paradise with a Purpose.jpg)" style="width:100%; height:300px"></div>
```

Does any know why if valid for img but invalid for background? any suggestion would be great.

Comment: As much as I hate the w3schools... Look up [url encoding](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)

Comment: I would avoid using spaces in filenames. Replacing them with %20 in the URI might work, but I'd just swap the spaces for underscores in the actual file and be done with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the url to `http://www.zendez.com/beta/files/retreatphotos/larges/idretreat70/Mayacamas%20Ranch,%20Calistoga,%20California_%20Paradise%20with%20a%20Purpose.jpg` will probably work..

As I said in the comment, your url is not properly [urlencoded](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp). Url's are not allowed spaces. I'm assuming that the browser's know how to handle poorly written src attributes of img tags but fail on css, most likely because you don't encapsulate the url in quotes like so:

`background:url('http://www.zendez.com/beta/files/retreatphotos/larges/idretreat70/Mayacamas Ranch, Calistoga, California_ Paradise with a Purpose.jpg');`

Either way, try to avoid spaces all together in filenames, you will end up with less of a headache.

Comment: Perfect works as a charm!!! :) I used encodeURI in my javascript since I couldn't change all the code

Answer (score 1):

Put your URL in quotes.  That is ... you have:

```
background:url(http://yadda/yadda.jpg);
```

Change it to:

```
background:url('http://yadda/yadda.jpg');
```

When I do this, it works for me, both with spaces and with spaces replaced with `%20`.  Always try to keep things simple in filenames.  Punctuation and spaces may be handled badly by your filesystem or your programming environment.

Anyway, quotes are your friend.

Also, consider putting your style into  tags rather than embedding it in-line.

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
  .foo {
    background:url=('http://yadda/yadda.jpg') no-repeat;
  }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<p class="foo">Hello, world.</p>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that Im using jquery $.attr method to assing the background so I don't think I can assign quotes, the best option was to encode encodeURI method with javascript and works like a charm... but anyway is a good practice use quotes. I'm with you about using external css... but in this case is an assigning not an design issue...

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't place two Style attributes in the div, considering the last style might not work correctly.

Comment: Well actually the css is well was an encoding problem from jquery side I was assingning $("#id").attr("background",somefuncionTogetImage()); and shoul be
$("#id").attr("background",encodeURI(somefuncionTogetImage())); and works